# How do I wrap the code inside nested loops over first states and then years?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, nested

For example, in the attached R script, I have state == “CA” & year == 2010 in line 11. In line 174, I save the dataframe into a file called CA_2010.csv. I want to create a loop that then goes to state == “CA” & year == 2011 then save the dataframe into a file called CA_2011.csv. And it keeps going until it gets to  the end of the CSV file (AK_2013.csv).

Would you have any guidance on how to create an automated script for this?

```
data <- structure(list(state = c("CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", 
"CA", "CA", "CA", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "WA", "WA", "WA", 
"WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", 
"FL", "FL", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L), name = c("smith", "jones", 
"marx", "smith", "jones", "marx", "smith", "jones", "haas", "lee", 
"chen", "rose", "gonzalez", "prize", "smith", "dole", "smith", 
"dole", "west", "dole", "west", "perez", "gold", "brace", "watson", 
"roberts", "watson", "roberts", "mink", "white", "hope", "silver", 
"most", "hope", "silver", "most", "anders", "notts", "silver", 
"most", "anders", "notts", "lowell", "warren"), vote = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), bill = c(123L, 123L, 
123L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 345L, 345L, 345L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 
456L, 567L, 567L, 678L, 678L, 678L, 980L, 980L, 980L, 765L, 765L, 
765L, 765L, 432L, 632L, 632L, 632L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L), party = c("D", 
"R", "D", "D", "R", "D", "D", "R", "D", "D", "R", "D", "D", "R", 
"D", "R", "D", "R", "D", "R", "D", "R", "D", "R", "D", "D", "R", 
"D", "R", "D", "D", "R", "D", "D", "R", "D", "D", "R", "R", "D", 
"D", "R", "R", "R")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))


        data2 <- data %>%
      dplyr::select(
        state, year, name, vote, bill, party
      ) %>%
      filter(
        state == "CA" & year == 2010
      ) %>%
      group_by(state, year, name, party) %>%
      spread(bill, vote) %>%
      ungroup()
    
    write.csv(data2, "CA_2010.csv")
```

I'd assume that I'd have to write something like this, but this seems to have some issues:

```
for (i in unique(data$state)){
  for(j in unique(data$years)){
    
    data2 <- data %>%
      dplyr::select(
        state, year, name, vote, bill, party
      ) %>%
      filter(
        state == i & year == j
      ) %>%
      group_by(state, year, name, party) %>%
      spread(bill, vote) %>%
      ungroup()
    
    write.csv(data2, paste0(i, "_", j, ".csv"))
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be (1) `for (j in unique(data$years))`, (2) `state == i & year == j` and  (3) `write.csv(data2, paste0(i, "_", j, ".csv")`.

Comment: @MartinGal I made the edits you recommended but I don't see the CSV files. I just edited the original post to reflect your suggestions. How do I get it work?

Comment: It's `data$year` not `data$years`.

Answer (score 0):

With `purr`'s `map2` function instead of loop.

```
require(tidyverse)
create_csv <- function(the_state, the_year) {
  data %>%
    filter(state == the_state,
           year == the_year) %>%
    write.csv(file = paste0(the_state, "_", the_year, ".csv"))
}

map2(data$state, data$year, create_csv)
```